# NSMutableArray sort by title

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have `NSMutableArray` that can contain two objects:

`NSString` and this one :

```
@interface FileDownloadItem : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
.......
@end
```

And i want to be able to sort the `NSMutableArray` by or the title or the string.
Before i had the NSString in the array i use this command:

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
favoritesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[[FavoritesRep sharedFavoritesRep] favoritesArray] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]];
```

But now it's just crash.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of your crash?

Comment: There are some protocols your custom class needs to adhere to in order to make it useful in collection classes...

Comment: Am I correct when I understand that the array contains one FileDownloadItem and one NSString, not two FileDownloadItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proper solution:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArrayToSort sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if (! [obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        obj1 = [obj1 title];
    if (! [obj2 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        obj2 = [obj2 title];
    return [obj1 caseInsensitiveCompare:obj2];
}
```

Comment: Where i made compare between the two kind of objects?

Comment: @MTA You don't: first both objects are converted to strings, then those are being compared.

Comment: @MariusFalkenbergWaldal Both objects are converted only if they are not yet strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack:

```
@interface NSString (title)
- (NSString *)title;
@end

@implementation NSString (title)
- (NSString *)title { return self; }
@end
```

With this you can keep your existing code. But it clutters NSString's namespace and is not recommended for production code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution:

```
@implementation FileDownloadItem

- (NSString *)description
{
    return self.title
}

@end
```

To sort just use your existing code with a slightly modified sort descriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: This will work for the comparison, but might have other implications since description can be used for many other things.

Answer (score -1):

Since the objects are different, iOS doesn't know what to compare. You need to provide info on what part of the FileDownloadItem you want to compare to the string. You can try using a comparator. Something like this:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString *title = [obj1 valueForKeyPath:@"@title"];
    obj2;
    return (NSComparisonResult)[title compare:obj2];
}];
```

Comment: Did not downvote, but this is wrong: *Both* obj1 and obj2 can be a NSString *or* a FileDownloadItem.

Comment: @MartinR True, should have tested on them. But then I end up with what nikolai-ruhe answered later, so a bit late now :-)